# Export file intent for Xamarin/Android

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My Xamarin Forms app needs to export a data file (an encrypted stream of bytes) to an external location of the user's choosing (OneDrive or Google Drive, etc.).

It's working for iOS and UWP, but Android is stumping me. On iOS I'm using UIDocumentPickerViewController with mode Export To Service and (on UWP) FileSavePicker. For Android, I've tried using the ActionSend intent to no avail.

My latest failing attempt is:

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uri);
intent.SetType("*/*");
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Is there a better Intent or way to call this one? My primary requirement is the ability to share the file to OneDrive or Google Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I discovered was that I was doing a URI.FromFile() to get the url to share.

I found success with use of a File Provider and a call FileProvider.GetUriForFile(). Documentation for setting up and using File Provide can be found at https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html

Code excerpt:

```
var file = new Java.IO.File(sourceFilePath);
var fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Application.Context, "com.your-company.Xyzzy.fileprovider", file);
if ( fileUri != null ) {
    var shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
    shareIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, fileUri);
    shareIntent.SetDataAndType(fileUri, Application.Context.ContentResolver.GetType(fileUri));
    shareIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    shareIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    StartActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
}
```

The only downside to this is that the activity result returns cancelled immediately so there is no confirmation when the user is done. I'll tackle that in another post.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to accomplish this? My primary requirement is the ability to write the file to OneDrive or Google Drive.

It is not a good approach trying to write files to Google Drive or OneDrive, because unlike desktop, OneDrive/GoogleDrive on Mobiles won't sync files(upload to cloud) automatically for performance reason.

Please consider using Cloud APIs for OneDrive or Google Drive:

1. For Google Drive, you can use [Google Play Service for Xamarin](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents).

   Official documentation: [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro)

   Official Demo: [GoogleDrive-quick-start](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)

   Or you can use [Rest API of Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)
2. For One Drive, you can use Microsoft Graph API:

   Official Documentation:[Graph API Quick Start](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/get-started)

   Official Demo: [xamarin-csharp-connect-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/xamarin-csharp-connect-sample)

Comment: As the question states, I am specifically looking for an Android Intent to accomplish this. I am unsure why you would state it's a bad approach. How else is data to be shared? That's why we have cloud services. iOS and UWP give us convenient approaches. I am looking for the Android solution for providing similar behavior.